# How to quickly export the a whole column from a MySQL database table?

Tags: mysql, performance

I have a MySQL database table `t` with just two columns, `id` which is `INT(11)` and `val` which is `VARCHAR(255)`. There are several millions of rows. How to quickly export the a whole column of `id`?  Index is `id` and `val`, i.e. `id` is not unique in the column.

Is

```
SELECT DISTINCT id FROM t;
```

the best?

#### EDIT:

I'd like to save the result into a text file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To export the unique `id`s into a file **on the server** you can use

```
SELECT DISTINCT id FROM t INTO OUTFILE 'all_the_unique_ids';
```

You will then find the file `<mysql data dir>/<database name>/all_the_unique_ids` on the server.

If you want to have the file on the client you need to use a MySQL client, e.g. MySQL's own command line client:

```
mysql -e "SELECT DISTINCT id FROM t" > all_the_unique_ids
```

Comment: I know how to get output into file;  My main concern was that if `SELECT DISTINCT` is really the *fastest* way.  For example, would `mysql -e "SELECT DISTINCT id FROM t" | uniq > output.txt` be fast at all?  Could the fact that i need each row simply anything so might use some faster SQL query?

Comment: The only thing you can do to make it faster is to create an index. That way you trade some insert/update performance for better SELECT DISTINCT performance.

Comment: But `id` and `val` together already form a multi-column key.  Is that not enough?  I need to create an index for just `id`?

Comment: Oh, didn't see that. Yes, that's enough.